# Python string to dictionary with json (not working)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a text file like this :

"imei": "123456789",
"sim_no": "+90 xxx xxx xx xx",
"device_type": "standart",
"hw_version": "1.01",
"sw_version": "1.02"

and i want to convert to dictionary this file. Because i want to take values.

```
import json
from time import sleep

def buffer(data):
    dicto=json.loads(data) 
    print(type(dicto))      

file=open("config.txt", "r").read()
jsondata=json.dumps(file)  
buffer(jsondata)

result : <class 'str'>
```

When i working in shell like this :

```
>>> import json
>>> h = '{"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}'
>>> type(h)
<class 'str'>
>>> d=json.loads(h)
>>> d
{'foo2': 'bar2', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```

its working but i can't understand why my code not working. When i convert this file to dictionary i want to hold in a buffer. How can i hold this data inside array? Please excuse me i am new in Python.

Comment: Could you show you `config.txt` file?

Comment: "imei": "123456789",
"sim_no": "+90 xxx xxx xx xx",
"device_type": "standart",
"hw_version": "1.01",
"sw_version": "1.02"

Comment: It's exactly like that? With quotes?

Comment: Yes, all text like this.

Comment: Add the missing curly braces before calling `json.loads`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could just add the outer curly braces JSON requires:

```
with open('config.txt', 'r+') as f:
    newdata = '{{ {} }}'.format(f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(newdata)
```

Otherwise, the file is already JSON, so no actual use of the `json` module is required (unless you want to check if it's already legal before modifying, or verify legality after).